# Sending e-mails to the admin after proper registration from local WAMP server to google account - PHP, MySQL, SwiftMailer

Tags: php, mysql, swiftmailer

After a proper user registration (data is logged to the database and registration is running correctly) I would like to receive an email to a gmail account confirming the success. I am working on a WAMP local server and I am using the SwiftMailer library.

Below the code, which unfortunately this e-mail does not send me.

```
<?php
$transporter = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('smtp.gmail.com', 465, 'ssl')
                    ->setUsername('testphp2017@gmail.com')
                    ->setPassword('testxxx');

                $mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transporter);

                $mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transporter);
                $message = Swift_Message::newInstance('Wonderful Subject')
                    ->setFrom(array('testphp2017@gmail.com'))
                    ->setTo(array('testphp2017@gmail.com'))
                    ->setBody('Test Message Body')
                ;
```

Comment: what do your error-logs say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is missing the send function:

```
$result = $mailer->send($message);
```

Comment: Yes, my bad, but after added this line of code after registration chrome show me that:

Expected response code 250 but got code "535", with message "535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at 535 5.7.8 https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials s26sm403221ljd.27 - gsmtp "

Comment: Have you verified the username and password you are using are correct?

Comment: The problem appears in security settings in google account. But thank you Jason for that code line. I dont know how i can forget about that ;)